# Tomcat Adapter is not visible in kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

When I started my eclipse, server is missing from server view and my problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228818/eclipse-kepler-server-not-creating) but answers are not there, Please let me know how can I get my tomcat server adapter in eclipse back.

I have tried downloading additional adapters.

I have tried all the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983453/running-tomcat-with-eclipse-kepler)

My eclipse is kepler Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to install "JST Server Adapters".
Tomcat adapter is coming in JST Server Adapters.

Go to help ---> Install New Software.
Add below link in Eclipse
http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates

Try to install "JST Server Adapters".

Comment: I have mentioned this that I have already tried this thing still I am not able to get server.

Comment: Can you try uninstalling it and install it again using this link. I was facing the same issue yesterday. Uninstalled and the installed it again. It worked for me.