# Which Eclipse to download for Java EE (having support for Tomcat 8)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have had Eclipse Kepler version which did not support Tomcat 8. I have tried doing what this post said - [How to use Tomcat 8 in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868232/how-to-use-tomcat-8-in-eclipse).
But I could not get the Tomcat v8. Finally I also followed this post - [Running tomcat with eclipse kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983453/running-tomcat-with-eclipse-kepler) but after doing what this guy said, my eclipse no longer opens!

I would like to install a completely new Eclipse version that supports Web Development tools and has support for Tomcat 8 by default. Which one should I go for? I know there is a Eclipse IDE for Java Developers and Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. I should choose the latter i guess, but which version should I install? Luna, Kepler, Indigo, etc.?? Please correct me if I'm wrong but these are the names given to different version that came at different times right?

Comment: May I please know what is wrong with the question? I am having a genuine problem here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Tomcat 8 in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868232/how-to-use-tomcat-8-in-eclipse)

Comment: @owlstead I'm sorry but my question is a little different. I have also mentioned that the answer to the post did NOT help me when I had eclipse Kepler. I also wanted to make sure that I download the correct version this time.

Comment: But I just installed Eclipse Luna 4.4. Isn't that the latest? And isn't it the only version with support for Tomcat 8?

Comment: Ah, the list on Wiki didn't list the last one, I'm going fine, aint I? I'll upvote to make it better. But in that case, always test against the latest release!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Eclipse Luna 4.4. It offers the following [features](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uk5XFUj6vxY):

1. Java EE 7 Support
2. Java SE 8 Support
3. Apache Tomcat 8 Support (The one you desire)
4. Split Editors

You may also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868232/how-to-use-tomcat-8-in-eclipse) SO answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for Juno. I am using it these days with tomcat and having no problem. I do not exactly whether it support Tomcat 8 or not as Tomcat 8 is still under development and just few releases has been made.

You can download Juno from:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/juno/sr2

Thanks